# simple php mailing issue

Tags: php, email

i have this php mailing and so far is working, but when i receive the mails i dont get the name, email or tel information from the contact form, i just get subject and message. how could i fix this? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$tel       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['tel'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'example@example.com';//replace with your email


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;

?>
```

Comment: ... concatenate the fields you're missing onto `$message`?

Comment: `$message` is what you are sending as the email body. But you have not put any of the fields you want to see in the `$message` variable

Comment: got it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including anything other than `$message` in the message body of the email. See [this reference on mail()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) for more information.

I've provided an example of how you would include those other variables in the message below:

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$tel       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['tel'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'yorchdiazc@hotmail.com';//replace with your email

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

// add name, email, tel to message - choose whichever markup you wish
$message_body = "
Name = " . $name . "<br>
Email = " . $email . "<br>
Tel = " . $tel . "<br>
Message = " . $message;

mail($to, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

die;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it. really helpful :)

Comment: @YorchDiazContreras please accept the answer if it resolved your issue